# Change color of bar's in excel chart

Tags: powershell

I wrote the below code to get excel bar chart. but the color is coming as blue for all the bars.

```
$file = 'D:\Uptime_Last Week.xlsx'
$workbook = $xl.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.item(1)

$objCharts = $sheet.ChartObjects()
$objChart = $objCharts.Add(500, 500, 500, 500)

$dataRange = $sheet.range("A1:B5")
$ColumnCount = $sheet.Columns
$chart=$sheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart

$chart.seriesCollection(1).Select() | Out-Null
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels() | out-Null
$objChart.Chart.SetSourceData($dataRange)
```

Please let me know how can i change the colors.
below is the data i have

```
Name    Avg
Network 99.99716242
Unix    99.98140079
Windows 99.84750824
storage 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$file = 'D:\Uptime_Last Week.xlsx'

$excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible       = $true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false 

$workbook            = $excel.Workbooks.Open( $file, [System.Type]::Missing, $false ) 
$sheet               = $workbook.Worksheets.item(1)

$objCharts = $sheet.ChartObjects()
$objChart  = $objCharts.Add(500, 500, 500, 500)

$dataRange   = $sheet.Range("A1:B5")
$ColumnCount = $sheet.Columns
$chart       = $sheet.Shapes.AddChart().Chart

# color each bar

$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.Color = 255
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).Interior.Color = 255 * 255
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).Interior.Color = 255 * 255 * 255
$chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Interior.Color = 0

[void]$chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels() 
[void]$objChart.Chart.SetSourceData($dataRange)
```